# What should I use for updating data from android in specific rate?

Tags: android

I have android application. It need to download data from internet for example every 1 hour. It will run 6 asynctask that will download data from internet and save them to database. I'm just asking, what should I use? AlarmManager or Service? It will be very helpfull for me, if you will give me some links for example of downloading data in specific rate.

Thank you

Comment: title and question don't match up

Comment: A service is useful for operations you want done whether the app is closed or not. Alarm manager is great if you want scheduled events in the future. Hopefully this will aid you make a decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm just asking, what should I use? AlarmManager or Service?

Both, if you are going to do the HTTP work yourself. You may need to make that be [a `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) or otherwise use a `WakeLock` to keep the device awake.

If you would prefer to use `DownloadManager` for the HTTP work, that would save you having to deal with the service, the `AsyncTasks`, and the `WakeLock`. In this case, you could use `AlarmManager` and a `BroadcastReceiver`. However, `DownloadManager` is only for API Level 9 and higher.